# Scaling with css just leaves whitespace around

Tags: css, scale

so I want to scale a div down, but when I do that, it still takes up the same amount of space, but there is just whitespace instead, and then it is small in the middle.

But I want it to actually take up less space, and allow the elements above and below to be closer to it.

Heres an example of the problem:
HTML:

```
<h1>A title goes here</h1>
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span><br>
    <span>Some text here</span><br>
    <span>Some text here</span><br>
    <span>Some text here</span><br>
    <span>Some text here</span><br>
    <span>Some text here</span><br>
  </div>
<p>And some more text here</p>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  width: fit-content;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/Tobias-Hewel/pen/ExvdENN

Comment: you cannot do this with scale, you need to reduce the width/height

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS transform: scale does not change DOM size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835144/css-transform-scale-does-not-change-dom-size)

Comment: Yes, it explains why it is that way, but I still don't know what to do

Answer (score -2):

Add styles to the `html` and `body` elements to reset all the whitespaces.

```
html,
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This does remove any whitespace on the edges of the screen, but that is not what I am talking about. This is a specific problem to do with scaling.